# How to get index with known value as string in arraylist?

Tags: vb.net

I have ArrayList with multi dimensional values in Structure as ArrayList

```
Structure
(0)=> Mstructure.ABCD
       Area (these are value of ABCD)
       Name
(1)=> Mstructure.EFGH
           Area
           Name
```

I want to know the index of string ABCD.

I tried

```
Dim myIndex as Integer = Structure.IndexOf("ABCD")
Dim myIndex = Array.IndexOf(Structure.ToArray(), myString)
```

This returned only -1. I want to get 0 if string is ABCD

**EDITED**

Structure is defined as ArrayList. I can iterate over it if I use loop e.g

```
Structure(i).GetType().Name = "ABCD"
```

I have checked if it exists in the ArrayList

```
Dim result = Structure.ToArray().Any(Function(x) x.ToString().Contains("ABCD"))
```

But I want to know the index of the multidimensional ArrayList without looping it. I want to get the index of Mstructure.ABCD. Msttructure.ABCD has values inside it but without knowing those values I want to get the index value.

```
(0){Mstructure.ABCD}
(1){Mstructure.EFGH}
(2){Mstructure.IJKL}
```

Comment: If you used a `List(Of YourStructure)` instead of an ArrayList (which was obsolete 20 years ago) then you could do `Dim myIndex = theList.FindIndex(Function(c) c.Area = "ABCD")`.

Comment: @Andrew Morton You can always call `ArrayList.ToList()` (yes, all right, don't say it :).  @ritesh khadka But you can simply find the Struct with `Dim theStruct = arrayList.OfType(Of Mstructure).FirstOrDefault(Function(str) str.Name = "EFGH")`. Or whatever these structs are named and built. Couldn't you post the actual structures instead of this pseudo-code?

Comment: It is messy, but: `Dim myIndex = yourArrayList.ToArray().Cast(Of YourStructureName).ToList().FindIndex(Function(b) b.Area = "ABCD")`.

Comment: @Andrew Morton `ToList()` is enough (unless you did it on purpose, to make it *messier* :) Anyway, the OP probably needs to access the struct itself. What would they do with the index alone? To test existence, `FirstOrDefault` will work.

Comment: @Jimi Option Strict On insists that I do the `Cast`. I imagine that they will be able to take over the entire Tri-State Area when the indexinator is complete.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I meant that `ToArray()` is not needed here: `Dim theIndex = arrayList.OfType(Of Mstructure).ToList().FindIndex(Function(str) str.Name = "EFGH")`, but you can also do something like: `dim theIndex = arrayList.IndexOf(arrayList.OfType(Of Mstructure).FirstOrDefault(Function(str) str.Name = "EFGH"))` (or whatever else can be used to identify a struct by *name*). Otherwise, to get a struct reference, simply `dim theStruct = arrayList.OfType(Of Mstructure).FirstOrDefault(Function(str) str.Name = "EFGH")`

Comment: @Jimi Oh, thanks, I didn't know about `OfType` working like that.

Comment: I have updated the code. I want to find the index without using (Name, Area etc.). To use Mstructure.Name or Area. It must be in loop.

Answer (score 0):

hhmmm i would use collections instead, or create an object with multi collections to make it easier for me... Have you thought of that?